# How can I make on viber those who call me to hear them normal and not slow motion?

Tags: sony-xperia-z3

I have Xperia z3. I know that I have a function so that the people who call are speaking slow and I ve turned it off. But for some reason on viber it does the same and there isn't anything to make it stop. Can you help me please..?

Comment: If you know you have a "function", please state what that function is.